# Getting Weird Invalid Token Error Message At Postman

Tags: laravel, api, rest, jwt, postman

I'm trying to connect to an API of a website using Token Authorization in Postman.

So the URL that I'm trying to connect is a GET URL that goes like this:

```
https://seller.digikala.com/api/v1/profile/
```

And then at Postman, I set the `Authorization` type to `BearerToken` and copied and pasted the token.

And Headers is also set to `Content-Type` of `application/json`:

[image: capture]

But I don't know why I get this error:

```
{
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Invalid token!"
}
```

I also test the token at the jwt.io website and it says: **Invalid Signature!**

[image: capture2]

So the question is, does the website provide me a wrong and invalid token (because I just copy and paste it and no chance of entering an incorrect token)?

What are the other ways for authorizing this token and how can I get the proper response?

Comment: The tokens that I come across usually have a number before them like `12|` followed by the rest of the token. Yours does not have that. I am not sure if all forms of token have that, but that could be the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

### BearerToken is not always JWT

`BearerToken` is a type of Authorization Header, you can pass to an http endpoint.

BearerTokens can have multiple `token_type`, like:

`jwt`,
`api_token`,
...

the `BearerToken` is not always `jwt`, it can have multiple `algorithm`.

the `12|xxx` format is like api_token

> Note: one of the signs if you want to know the token is jwt, if its
> format is url encoded string with 2 dots, (xxx.yyy.zzz) its a chance
> that it would be `JWT` token

### Validating JWT

in the jwt.io you should provide the **digikala.com** public key to validate the signature.

> It said invalid token, because you haven't provide, **digikala**
> public key

but as decoder showed up, the token you have provided is a **jwt token** with payload data of :

```
{
  "token_id" : 970,
  "payload" : null
}
```

### TD;DR

I guess you can access if you login again and try new token

Comment: Please would you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70052445/how-to-validate-jwt-token-in-postman-properly