# Can not update data with POST request in Postman

Tags: json, laravel, api, postman, api-key

I have an API token from **digikala.com** and I want to make a POST request for **Updating variant**.

So as the [documentation](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2413517/UUxui9bS#8ce1f76f-dabb-4d7e-a344-dd419a2a133c) says, I have to send this kind of data as Body raw:

```
{
    "site": "digikala",
    "shipping_type": "both",
    "seller_stock": 10,
    "max_per_order": 10,
    "digikala_lead_time": 2,
    "ship_by_seller_lead_time": 48,
    "is_archived": false,
    "is_active": true,
    "price": 12000,
    "gold_wage": null,
    "non_gold_parts_cost": null,
    "non_gold_parts_wage": null,
    "gold_profit": null
}
```

But I get **`404 Not Found`** error:

[image: capture_main]

So what's going wrong here? How can I properly get the data in this situation?

Not that I have properly defined the API_KEY because I tested it with another GET request and it was working fine.

Comment: I have looked at the api doc, & I couldnt found any `/login` endpoint.

Comment: from where you have achieved the token ? I need one to test against the api

Comment: Is there any more information returned, such as a reason string, in the body of the response?

Comment: @Tony No only some html and Status is also `404 Not Found`.

Comment: `POST` is usually used to create a resource, not update, but that's not your fault as you did not write the API. You say the API_KEY is ok "because I tested it with another GET request", was the GET request to retrieve the variant_id 18380831, or just to test some other end point?

Comment: can you add api route in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this is strange but changing the post to a put method allowed the request and also adding an extra forward slash after the request worked. I just think the api is not very well documented

[image]

Comment: I forgot the `/` after the url